# How to attach a sql server database from one server to another using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I have been trying to migrate sql server databases from one instance to another in different servers(same domain) using Powershell. The pre-requisite for this migration is that the powershell script has to be executed from the destination server. I successfully performed the migration using backup and restore. Please help me with attaching the database using powershell. I cannot use invoke-command as firewall is enabled and cannot add exceptions.

Comment: Did you search?  http://andrewmorgan.ie/2011/12/backup-and-restore-sql-databases-using-powershell/